# Getting the image source of a dynamic image django / wagtail

Tags: html, django, image, wagtail

I want to add an dynamic wagtail image to my template with the source.

When I do:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}
{% image page.specific.main_image width-400 %}
```

The output is:

```
<img src="[dynamic image source]" width="400" height="171" alt="[dynamic image alt]">
```

Is it possible to only get the src of the dynamic image?

I want to add the image as a background like:

```
<div style="background-image:url([dynamic image source])">
```

Does anybody know if this is possible??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you write the image tag as:

```
{% image page.specific.main_image width-400 as my_image %}
```

this will write the image information to the variable `my_image`, rather that outputting a tag immediately. You can then write:

```
<div style="background-image:url({{ my_image.url }})">
```

Comment: Great, I used this to create a customisable meta image tag in my wagtail sites base template :  <meta property="og:image" content="{% if page.seo_image %}{% image page.seo_image fill-300x300 as img %}{{img.url}}{% else %}{% static 'images/logo-square.png' %}{% endif%}">. Thank you